# Lumen storing images error: Path is outside of the defined root

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I am trying to accept an image in my frontend react app to my api and then store it back into a path within the frontend app however I get the following error:

> Path is outside of the defined root, path:
>   [../../frontend/public/productimages/__test.jpg]

Basically I have used a multiform data to upload the image file.

If I do this: `$file->storeAs('public', '__test.jpg');` Then the file is stored under Lumen backend directory but I would rather have in under my frontend directory.

When i log the `base_path()` in my Lumen backend API i get the following:

> C:\Projects\website\backend

How can I instead store the image in:

> C:\Projects\website\frontend\public

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the file publicly like this:

```
$file->storeAs('productimages', '__test.jpg', 'public');
```

This way, you're file will be stored on `storage/app/public/productimages`. To make your file accessible from the web, you should create a symbolic link from `public/storage` to `storage/app/public` via artisan:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Then you can access your file on `public/storage/productimages` which is accessible through web: `http://your-domain.com/storage/productimages/__test.jpg`

You can also manually create a symbolic link from `C:\Projects\website\frontend\public` to `C:\Projects\website\backend\storage\app\public` on windows cmd:

```
mklink /d "C:\Projects\website\frontend\public" "C:\Projects\website\backend\storage\app\public"
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem#the-public-disk) for more info.

Comment: unfortunately I am using Lumen so the storage:link command wont work

Comment: Is there no way to save the images directly to my frontend path for images? `C:\Projects\website\frontend\public\productimages`

Comment: @strangeQuirks try to run this command instead on windows cmd to create a symolink: `mklink /d "C:\Projects\website\backend\public\storage" "C:\Projects\website\backend\storage\app\public"` check this answer for more details: https://superuser.com/a/1020825/1116552

Comment: `Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` I can navigate to both of those paths too in my file explorer, so not sure why I get this issue. `C:\Projects\website\backend\public\storage\images` is where my images are stored in lumen and `C:\Projects\sustainableheroes\frontend\public\productimages` is currently where I have files uploaded and is where I want them to be when i upload from lumen

Comment: remove your `C:\Projects\sustainableheroes\frontend\public` directory and try again.